# sudo apt update fails after new ubuntu install

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a home PC. The first thing I did was run `sudo apt update`. I then get this error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
```

I also get a popup window shortly after clean install "`Hotspot Login`", but internet works fine.

In `Other Software` I have two entries, `Canonical Partners` and `Canonical Partners(Source Code)`.

I have searched questions and answers, some hint that it might be the firewall or internet proxy settings, though none of them hint at troubleshooting that, from which I have seen.  I believe this is where my error is originating from?

EDIT: more information

when pasting the two http: address' into my browser, it works.

Output of command as requested by FedonKadifeli:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
grep: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*: No such file or directory
```

I borrowed someone else's wifi router with different ISP, and then it works. Which confirms my suspicion that it has something to do with internet proxy or network settings.

Comment: Did you retry a few times? Do you get the same error consistently? Can you [edit] your question and paste the output of the command `grep -v -e '^#' -e '^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` ?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, thanks. Please see updated question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)